# Java array in for loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to create a menu for toll data entry that runs in a loop until the user requests to exit. The menu will ask the user to enter data which is stored in an array and keeps adding to the array until the user exits from the menu.
The menu should look as follows:

Toll Data Entry Menu

[image]

My menu works fine until asking the user to enter the trip date. The menu will continue to ask for each trip date up until the end of the length of the array (30 - arbitrary length). 
I however want the menu to ask for the trip date, store the value entered by the user, then move onto entering the entry point, store value, etc and then loop back to the selection for the user to enter the above details again for a separate trip until they choose to exit. (I need to print these values later on) I'm not sure how to store the values from the user separately without prompting the user to enter all (30) values at the one time. 
Should I be using an array or is there another way to store multiple values for a looped menu?

Hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: You can accomplish this by using a single for loop instead of 3 separate ones.  And within that, set each array value equal to the current iteration.

Comment: "Should I be using an array"... looks like you're already using several of them.  Anyway, if I understand your question, I think all you need to do is rearrange your code so that it's in one loop instead of three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch the complete set of details one at a time, you just need a single `for` loop as:

```
String[] datesA = new String [30];
int[] entryP = new int [30];
int[] exitP = new int [30];

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter trip date: ");
    datesA[i] = inputA.nextLine();  
    // User to enter entry point
    System.out.println("Enter entry point: ");
    entryP[j] = inputA.nextInt();
    // User to enter exit point
    System.out.println("Enter exit point: ");
    exitP[k] = inputA.nextInt();
}
```

---

To improve the implementation though think over the lines of creating an object that includes all the details in one as :

```
class TollDataEntry {
    String entryDate;
    int entryPoint;
    int exitPoint;
    .... getter, setter etc.
}
```

and then use an array or Collection of this object to store the details of each `TollDataEntry` with those three values as a single entity.